# How to render a stateless component before mounting?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Currently I'm generating the `Table` component upon clicking the button, but I want the table to generate right as I load the page. Here is the parent component that I click to generate the table.

```
render() {
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.sellItem}>
           Sell Item
        </button>
        <Tables sellers={this.state.sellers} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the table (stateless component) that I'm generating upon clicking the button.

```
export default ({ sellers, header }) => {
return (
<div>
  <Table>
    <TableHeader>
      <TableRow>
        {
          header.map((headerName, index) => {
            return (
              <TableHeaderColumn key={`thc-${index}`}>
                {headerName.name}
              </TableHeaderColumn>
            )
          })
        }
        <TableHeaderColumn />
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
      {sellers.map((currentValue, index) =>
        <TableRowColumn>{currentValue}</TableRowColumn>
      )}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</div>
  )
}
```

How can I generate this table upon loading my parent component? I can't render things in the `componentWillMount`, so what do I do?

Comment: without seeing it you can probably move whatever code you have in this.sellItem to componentDidMount

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to render the Tables component before the actual component ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI I'm trying to render the Tables component right as the parent component renders so that both can show at the same time. However, the Tables component only shows when I click the `sellItem` button

Comment: @brub The thing is sellItem is meant to add data into the table, not meant to generate the table, just update

Comment: @JorahFriendzone first of all, children are rendered fist. Secondly, <Table> is generated and rendered. the only thing is, the content of TableBody is not generated if sellers.length === 0. try adding <p>lorem</p> as a sibling to <table> inside your stateless compoent, and you'll see it is rendered

Comment: Is this where you render that stateless component? `<Tables sellers={this.state.sellers} />` ? What may be happening is that state is empty until you run the sellItem code.  As @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI says you probably are rendering that table there is just nothing in your state yet. So initialize sellers in your constructor.

Comment: @brub Yes, that's where I render my stateless component. I just checked and you guys are right. The `sellers` state I pass in is empty until I run the sellItem code.